# main.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined index: default in CompositeConfigProvider.php on line 160

Tags: magento2, multi-vendor

I have currently a problem with my Magento 2 (2.3.2)

I'm using the Webkul multi vendor module and when I open a seller profile, the profile view is empty.

I've checked the `system.log` and got this:

> [2019-07-31 08:28:54] main.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined index: default
>   in
>   /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-cms/Model/Wysiwyg/CompositeConfigProvider.php
>   on line 160 [] []

```
    /**
 * Update config using config provider by active editor path
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject $config
 * @param array $configProviders
 * @return \Magento\Framework\DataObject
 */
private function updateConfig($config, array $configProviders)
{
    $adapterType = $this->getActiveEditorPath($config);
    //Extension point to update plugin settings by adapter type
    $providerClass = isset($configProviders[$adapterType])
        ? $configProviders[$adapterType]
        : $configProviders['default'];     <--### Here is the Error position ###
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Wysiwyg\ConfigProviderInterface $provider */
    $provider = $this->configProviderFactory->create($providerClass);
    return $provider->getConfig($config);
}
```

Somehow the `$configProvider` is empty, but I don't know why it is empty.

Did someone had the same error?

Greetings

Comment: have you tried contacting webkuls support-team?

Comment: yes, the problem is, that the support is already expired.

Comment: is your module-version up-to-date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following code in the app/etc/di.xml file

```
<type name="Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\CompositeConfigProvider">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="variablePluginConfigProvider" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="default" xsi:type="string">Magento\Variable\Model\Variable\ConfigProvider</item>
        </argument>
        <argument name="widgetPluginConfigProvider" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="default" xsi:type="string">Magento\Widget\Model\Widget\Config</item>
        </argument>
        <argument name="wysiwygConfigPostProcessor" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="default" xsi:type="string">Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\DefaultConfigProvider</item>
        </argument>
        <argument name="galleryConfigProvider" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="default" xsi:type="string">Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Gallery\DefaultConfigProvider</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Flush the cache and check whether this solution works for you.

Comment: can you look at this similar issue? i'm not sure why it's suddenly caused that https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/297085/notice-undefined-index-default-in-vendor-magento-module-catalog-batchsiz  thanks